# How can I run a query in the views in the context of the user access?

Tags: 7, views, database, users

How can I run a query in the views in the context of the user?
E.g. using `EntityFieldQuery` I can run

> $query->addMetaData('account', user_load(1));

is there any equivalent for `$view->query`?

Answer (score 2):

I've found possibility to do it in `hook_views_post_build`:

```
function MY_MODYLE_views_post_build($view) {
  if($view->name == 'MY_VIEW_NAME') {
    $query = $view->build_info['query'];
    $query->addMetaData('account', user_load(47));
  }
}
```

I've noticed that we have `SelectQuery` object only after query build (in views.inc `$this->query->build($this);`).

After it only one hook is executed `views_post_build`.